# Nuxt3 and server routes: Data streaming in chucks on localhost, but not when deployed to Netlify

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify, nuxtjs3

I built a demo chatbot using Nuxt3 and the Open AI API. I am streaming the data in chunks and it works nicely on localhost. But, when I deploy to Netlify, it is dumped all at once in the UI.

Why does it work perfectly on localhost but not on Netlify?

**Update: OK, it looks like Netlify uses HTTP/2 and this may cause the data streaming to behave differently?**

`server/api/chat.post.js`:

```js
import { getChatStream } from '../utils/ai'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { messages } = await readBody(event)
  console.log(1, messages)
  const stream = await getChatStream({ messages })
  return sendStream(event, stream)
})
```

`server/utils/ai.js`:

```js
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai'

const config = useRuntimeConfig()

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY || config.OPENAI_API_KEY
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

const systemPrompts = [
  {
    role: 'system',
    content:
      "..."
  },
  {
    role: 'user',
    content:
      "..."
]

export const getChatStream = async ({ messages }) => {
  const response = await openai.createChatCompletion(
    {
      max_tokens: 2048,
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      temperature: 0.5,
      messages: [...systemPrompts, ...messages],
      stream: true
    },
    { responseType: 'stream' } // The API response will be streamed
  )
  return response.data
}
```

`composables/chat-stream.js`:

```js
// composables/chat-stream.js
// This file defines a composable function called useChatStream that handles the OpenAI API response stream we get as a response from getAnswer().
const resolveStream = async ({
  data,
  onChunk = () => { },
  onReady = () => { },
  stream
}) => {
  const reader = stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader()
  while (true) {
    const stream = await reader.read()
    if (stream.done) break

    const chunks = stream?.value
      .replaceAll(/^data: /gm, '')
      .split('\n')
      .filter((c) => Boolean(c.length) && c !== '[DONE]')
      .map((c) => JSON.parse(c))

    for (let chunk of chunks) {
      const content = chunk.choices[0].delta.content
      if (!content) continue
      data.value += chunk.choices[0].delta.content
      onChunk({ data: content })
    }
  }

  onReady({ data: data.value })
}

export const useChatStream = ({
  onChunk = () => { },
  onReady = () => { },
  stream
}) => {
  const data = ref('')

  resolveStream({
    data,
    onChunk,
    onReady,
    stream
  })

  return {
    data: readonly(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Believe it needs to use Netlify Edge feature.